# Implemetation of tabs in Django templates or Jquery

Tags: jquery, django, django-templates

I am building an django app with tab navigation. And when the tab is clicked only the middle portion of the page is changed and rest remains the same. I also want to put a kind of loading signal that space when someone clicks on the tab and its being loaded. Please help me if django template will work or should i use jquery.

Comment: Hi Saransh. Can you please add a bit more detail to your question (preferably with some code)?

Comment: I really dont understand what help the code can do. And I m looking for suggestion not help in any codes. I want to know whats the best way to implement it and than only i will write the code na

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the loading signal, there are number of ways you could achieve the result you're after.

**Without using javascript/jquery**

Each tab that is clicked would do a complete page load.  A Django template could be used to fill in the common parts of the screen, the middle could be rendered depending on the tab clicked.  You could use template inheritance to avoid duplication.  Without help from javascript it may not be possible to have a signal displayed during a page reload after a new tab is clicked.

**Using jquery**

With jquery it's possible to use AJAX to request page content from the server for the tab just clicked.  It's up to you to decide what data to serve as part of the AJAX request from Django.

You could choose to have Django serve out a JSON representation of your data, with the content being handled client side by javascript libraries which do the formatting.  In this instance no templating would be required.

Or, you could have Django serve out data for each tab as rendered HTML which you simply insert into the DOM client side.  In this instance you probably would use Django templates to format the tab HTML data.

With any of the javascript options it is possible to attach an event handler to your loading functions which display an appropriate loading signal.

**Summary**

In answer to your question as to whether to use jquery *or* templates?  It depends.  You may want to use both.

Comment: Yeah..I think I will try to combine both by putting the templates inside the jquery request. I will get back to you as to how it worked

Answer (score 0):

am also implemented same tabs concept in my Django application :),

for achieve this you need to use jQuery this [link1](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#cookie) and [link2](http://www.my-html-codes.com/jquery-tabs-my-first-plugin) will give you some idea.

and if you want to load only clicked tab content use Jquery click event and Ajax call for that see [this](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AJAX)